# define a map function that only returns city names longer than 5 characters. Instead of other names - a line with a hyphen ("-")

Tags: python-3.x

The names of cities are entered in one line separated by a space.
You need to define a map function that only
returns city names longer than 5 characters.
Instead of other names - a line with a hyphen ("-").
Generate a list of the obtained values ​​and display it
on the screen in one line separated by a space.

```
cities = [i.replace(i, '-') for i in input().split() if len(i) < 5]
print(cities)


Input
cities = ['Moscow', 'Ufa', 'Vologda', 'Tula', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
Output
         ['Moscow', '-', 'Vologda', '-', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
```

Comment: Looks like homework, have you tried any code at all? if so, please post it here

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your problem. The easiest way to do that is to include the **text** based version of the code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 2):

if you can use a lambda function then:

```
cities = ['Moscow', 'Ufa', 'Vologda', 'Tula', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
print(list(map(lambda x: '-' if len(x)<5  else x,cities)))
```

output:

```
['Moscow', '-', 'Vologda', '-', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
```

also if you want to do it without function map, only list comprehension:

```
cities = ['Moscow', 'Ufa', 'Vologda', 'Tula', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
print([ i.replace(i, '-') if len(i)<5 else i for i in cities  ])
```

output:

```
['Moscow', '-', 'Vologda', '-', 'Vladivostok', 'Habarovsk']
```

as mentioned by @JonSG, this option without the map function would be more efficient without replacing:

```
['-' if len(i) < 5 else i for i in cities]
```

Comment: @JonSG yes, you are right, this was just fixing the code posted by the OP